# Rotating RigidBody2Ds in Godot

Tags: 2d, physics, rotation, godot

I am practising programming games with the Godot Engine and I've been having some issues with `RigidBody2Ds`.

In this case I have a [`RigidBody2D`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html) as a child of a [`Node2D`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_node2d.html). The [`Node2D`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_node2d.html) is rotating and the [`RigidBody2D`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html) with it. However, as soon as I use [`apply_impulse()`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html#class-rigidbody2d-apply-impulse) it just returns to it's initial rotation point, which is zero.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Hi, could you post your code so that we can get a better idea of what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: More generally: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's definetely a strange behaviour since `aplly_impulse` [just increments linear and angular velocities](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/a71a5fc0c3f5d487d3f18c3b9e9a768052795e86/servers/physics_2d/body_2d_sw.h#L206), and not resets anything